# Wpf : checkbox three states set indeterminate state and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this checkbox

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Foo}" IsThreeState="True"></CheckBox>
```

If I would like to set default state to indeterminate my checkbox would be something like:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True" ></CheckBox>
```

Now I would like to combine the binding and set to indeterminate state. 
So my checkbox would be something like that:

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Foo, x:Null}" IsThreeState="True" ></CheckBox>
```

Can you help me to achieve this please ?

edit: in my MainWindows.xaml.cs I have this code for Foo property

```
private Boolean foo;
public Boolean Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set
    {
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: change the default value of Foo in the viewmodel...

Comment: When you set the type of your Foo property to bool? (= nullable boolean), it should work.

Comment: please Bruno can you read I edited my answer. I 'm new with C# and Xaml I'm not sure what is a nullable boolean type.

Comment: Ok Guys it works thank to you ! If you want to post the solution I will accept it. If not I will post my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here. First you're not calling `OnPropertyChanged()`. [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) needs to be called the other, is the Foo property needs to be nullable.

so it may look somehting like:

```
private bool? _foo;
puclic  bool? Foo
{
    get=> _foo;
    set {
       _foo = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I had to declare nullable Boolean. Thank you for the comment.
As GCamel and Bruno V mentioned I had to set the default value in MainWindowsView.xaml.cs constructor before InitializeComponent() method declaration.